# How to diagonalise the Laplace-de Rham operator on the 5-forms of AdS5 x S5?

Tags: hodge-theory

I am considering the manifold $M=AdS_5 \times S^5$. I would like to diagonalize the Laplace-de Rham operator $\Delta=(d+\delta)^2$ on the 5-forms of $M$. This yields complicated differential equations. Is there any clever way to solve them?

(Maybe this is an open problem, but if you have references discussing that kind of problems I would like to know them).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $AdS_5$?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu (Euclidean) anti-de Sitter space in 5 dimensions.